# How to stack with pandas multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data is in the following format (so 2 leading columns and then the data I want to stack)

```
[[TEXT, DATE, H1, H2, H3,...],
 ['ABA',01-01-2018,5,6,7,...],
 [...]]
```

And I need to convert it to (the same 2 leading columns and then the stacked data)

```
[[TEXT, DATE, PRICE, HOUR],
 ['ABA',01-01-2018,5,H1],
 ['ABA',01-01-2018,6,H2],
 ['ABA',01-01-2018,7,H3]]
```

I have tried stacking it with

```
data2=data.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'TEXT','level_1':'HOUR', 'level_2:'DATE',0:'PRICE'})
```

but I get as a result

```
[[TEXT, HOUR, PRICE],
 [0,TEXT,'ABA'],
 [0,DATE,01-01-2018],
 [0,1,5],
 [0,2,6]
 [0,3,7]]
```

I have tried playing with the stack function, but it never gives me the desired result.

Comment: possible dup. try `df.melt`

Comment: For stack, use `df.set_index(['TEXT','DATE']).stack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it even with a **single** (although substantially chained)
instruction:

```
data.set_index(['TEXT', 'DATE']).stack().reset_index()\
    .set_axis(labels=['TEXT', 'DATE', 'HOUR', 'PRICE'],
    axis='columns', inplace=False)[['TEXT', 'DATE', 'PRICE', 'HOUR']]
```

Elements:

- `data.set_index(['TEXT', 'DATE'])` - set *TEXT* and *DATE* as index.
- `.stack()` - generate a *Series* with column names as the added index level.
- `.reset_index()` - change this *Series* to a *DataFrame*,
  with index columns changed to "regular" columns.
- `.set_axis(...)` - set column names.
- `[['TEXT', ...]]` - reorder columns.

**Test**

I created the source DataFrame, with 2 rows, as:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([
    ['ABA', '01-01-2018',  5,  6,  7],
    ['CUX', '05-01-2018', 15, 16, 17]],
    columns=['TEXT', 'DATE', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3'])
```

The result of the above instruction is:

```
  TEXT        DATE  PRICE HOUR
0  ABA  01-01-2018      5   H1
1  ABA  01-01-2018      6   H2
2  ABA  01-01-2018      7   H3
3  CUX  05-01-2018     15   H1
4  CUX  05-01-2018     16   H2
5  CUX  05-01-2018     17   H3
```

Comment: And to unstack this same stack, the syntax is exactly the same?

Comment: Why do you need *unstack*?